# Calling Monitor.Enter inside a try statement vs calling it outside a try statement

Tags: c#, multithreading

a. On which cases this code fails:

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(someObj);
    //Do something important
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(someObj);
}
```

And this code doesn't fail:

```
Monitor.Enter(someObj);
try
{
    //Do something important
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(someObj);
}
```

b. Which one do you use when you are not wrapping a critical section with a using statement

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `lock(someObj)` would be simpler, and will use the new `Monitor` overloads in .NET 4 when availble.

In .NET 4, the following is preferred (emph: `lock` will **do this for you**):

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObj, ref lockTaken);
    // do something important
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
}
```

For why, see [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx)

But otherwise: the second; otherwise if the `Enter` call fails (**any** method call can fail), you then try and `Exit` a lock that *you don't have*.

Comment: I am using .Net 2 :(. But it is nice to know about those new overloads.

Comment: @Ikaso - well, use `lock` and it will use the best-available mechanism automatically...